# Google Play Music Player removal

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I can not find the package to remove Google Play Music from my applications. It no longer functions.
I am using 20.10
I have gone through the Applications window in the settings menu and clicked on the Open in Software button. It can not find the app in the store.
I have searched for the app in the terminal. I have run a dpkg --list list and searche dall those results and found nothing. I am just learning about the terminal but I am not sure what to ask it to do, but I want to remove this app. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `grep -R "Google Play" /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: /home/community/.local/share/applications/chrome-fahmaaghhglfmonjliepjlchgpgfmobi-Default.desktop:Name=Google Play Music

Comment: That's a Chrome app. Not a Debian, snap or flatpak package.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. That is awesome! And you know it is a chrome app because it is in the application folder for chrome. Makes total sense and now I know another way to search. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Most likely**, you have the snap version installed. A search should return a result like this:

```
sudo snap list | grep -i google | grep -i music
```

As you can see, `sudo snap list` is similar to `dpkg -l`. However, this command lists installed snap packages whereas `dpkg -l` lists installed deb packages.

Use `grep` to narrow the results and use the `-i` option for `grep` to disable case sensitivity for your search.

**If the package is listed**, you can use the `sudo snap remove` command followed by the package name you wish to uninstall. For example, if the package name is `google-play-music-desktop-player` you would use the following command:

```
sudo snap remove google-play-music-desktop-player
```

---

**In the same fashion**, you can list and search for installed flatpak packages like this (if you use flatpak):

```
flatpak list -a | grep -i google | grep -i music
```

The `-a` option for `flatpak` specifies all packages.

**To remove a flatpak package**, use the `flatpak uninstall` command followed by the package name.

more info about flatpak [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/flatpak-list.1.html) and [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/flatpak-uninstall.1.html)

---

**Alternatively**, there is a slim chance that you may have the old deb package installed. If this is the case, then

```
dpkg -l | grep -i google | grep -i music
```

should return a result.

If the `google-play-music-desktop-player` package is listed, you can use the following command to remove the package:

```
sudo apt purge google-play-music-desktop-player
```

Comment: Okay, all of that was awesome. But it still didn't show up in the terminal search. Flatpack didn't show up at all, and I had not heard of it, so I am guessing I do not use it. But this did help me see how the terminal works a little more.

Comment: The other option would be to open a terminal and run `top` or `htop` and while that is running, open the application. Then, the command for all running applications show in the right hand column so when you open the app, the command should show up there. Once you know the command for the application, it will be easier for us to figure out which application it is.

Comment: Thank you, it was a chrome app. But this is a great command to know too.Thank you for your help.